# Restrict addeventlistener of chrome webrequest to the current tab or the main window of the extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to fix some issues in an existing extension of Chrome. The extension is supposed to change the user agent of the sub frame which is a part of it. Now the problem is that when the event happens and I change the user agent of the header it is reflecting on all the tabs in browser and forcing the rest of the secured logins in those tabs to log off. I want to change the user agent of only that particular tab of the extension. Here is the code I am using in background.js

```js
var requestFilter = {
    urls: [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
};

chrome.tabs.query({
        'active': true,
        'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT
    },
             
    function(tabs) {
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
            var headers = [];
            headers = details.requestHeaders;
            if (!localStorage['user-agent']) {


                return;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                if (headers[i].name != 'User-Agent') {
                    headers[i].name = 'User-Agent';
                    headers[i].value =

                        localStorage['user-agent'];
                }
            }
            return {
                requestHeaders: headers
            };
        }, requestFilter, ['requestHeaders', 'blocking']);
    });

function focusOrCreateTab(url) {
    chrome.windows.getAll({
        "populate": false
    }, function(windows) {
        var existing_tab = null;
        for (var i in windows) {
            var tabs = windows[i].tabs;
            for (var j in tabs) {
                var tab = tabs[j];
                if (tab.url == url) {


                    existing_tab = tab;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (existing_tab) {
            chrome.tabs.update(existing_tab.id, {
                "selected": true
            });
        } else {
            chrome.tabs.create({
                "url": url,
                "selected": true
            });
        }
    });
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var manager_url = chrome.extension.getURL("youTube_tool.html");
    focusOrCreateTab(manager_url);
});
```

Kindly help me with this. I have been stuck for two weeks :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `chrome.tabs.query({active:true, ...})` call happens directly whenever the background script is loaded (thus once). This is incorrect, your callback will only receive the active tab from when the extension is loaded.

To fix this issue, call `chrome.tabs.query` whenever you want the active tab.
For your specific case, this is not needed at all: the [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) event receives a `Tab` object of the current tab when clicked. From the object, you can get the tab's ID using `tab.id` and assign this value to [`requestFilter.tabId`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter), as done below to restrict the event listener to that specific tab:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
        // do whatever you want.
    }, {
        urls: [
            '*://*/*'
        ],
        types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'],
        tabId: tab.id
    }, ['requestHeaders', 'blocking']);
});
```

Note: If you want to get the ability to remove the event, you have to save the callback in some global variable. The example below shows how to toggle an event listener that blocks all document requests in the current tab.

```js
var listeners = {};
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    if (listeners[tab.id]) {
        // Callback was previously set. Remove the listeners.
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(listeners[tab.id]);
        delete listeners[tab.id];
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
            text: '',
            tabId: tab.id
        });
    } else {
        listeners[tab.id] = function(details) {
            return {cancel: true};
        };
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(listeners[tab.id], {
            urls: ['*://*/*'],
            types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'],
            tabId: tab.id
        }, ['blocking']);
        // Show indicator to show that the extension is active.
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
            text: 'ON',
            tabId: tab.id
        });
    }
});

// Remove obsolete listener when the tab is closed.
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId) {
    if (listeners[tabId]) {
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(listeners[tabId]);
        delete listeners[tabId];
    }
});
```

Here is a minimal manifest.json to test the previous code (background.js):

```js
{
    "name": "Toggle requests for a specific tab",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "*://*/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Through Rob's solution I was able to prevent the other tabs from logging out but now all the other tabs are showing the mobile view even when I remove the extension . Thanks to Rob for helping me in the best possible way he could .

Answer (score 0):

It's plain and clear in [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter): a `RequestFilter` can contain a tab ID.

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    'active': true,
    'currentWindow': true // A much better way to write this
  },       
  function(tabs) {
    requestFilter.tabId = tabs[0].id; // Set the tab to filter on
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
      /* ... */
```

Comment: Thanks Xan . I tried the modifications but the browser is still behaving in the same manner .

Comment: Well, your code is a bit strange. Your query runs exactly once at the extension reload - so it binds to a single tab. And I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. I guess auth works by some kind of a session cookie - and if changing user-agent requires re-authentication, that would naturally invalidate the cookie for all tabs.

Comment: I have a hunch that a Chrome App approach with a `<webview>` tag would serve you better.

Comment: So by Chrome App approach do you mean that I will have to forget about the extension and develop a fresh application ? If yes , then I am sorry I will not be able to do that as client is too much worried about fixing this existing extension .

Comment: What I am trying to achieve here is to select a user agent from my extension's option.html and show the youtube video in an iframe with the changed user agent only within chrome extension's tab .