# Allow web requests based on document URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Within my extension, I'm trying to identify requests that are loaded as part of specifc pages. For examples, if the page:

```
https://www.arandomwebsite.com
```

Loads the following resources:

```
https://www.arandomwebsite.com/js/app.js
https://www.arandomwebsite.com/css/style.css
```

And makes a few API requests to:

```
https://www.arandomwebsite.com/api/users
```

Using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest, I want to know that `www.arandomwebsite.com/js/app.js` is loaded as a resource from `www.arandomwebsite.com`.

I've tried to do this using `chrome.tabs` to get the tab URL. As `chrome.tabs` is asynchronous I've used `onUpdated` and `onRemoved` to track tab changes. However, as `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` can fire before `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`, this doesn't work.

```
var allowedURL = "https://www.arandomwebsite.com/"

var tabs = {};

chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        tabs[tab.id] = tab;
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    tabs[tab.id] = tab;
});

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId) {
    delete tabs[tabId];
});

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
    return checkURL(details);
}, {
    urls: ['<all_urls>']
}, ['blocking']);

function checkURL(details) {
    if(details.type === 'main_type') {
        if(details.url === allowedURL) {
            // Allow the request
            return {
                cancel: false
            }
        }
        else {
            // Block the request
            return {
                cancel: true
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if(tabs[details.tabId].url === allowedURL) {
            // Allow the request
            return {
                cancel: false
            }
        }
        else {
            // Block the request
            return {
                cancel: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not much clear about your question, but if you want to restrict request for specific pages, have you ever considering filtering the request through tabId? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541467/restrict-addeventlistener-of-chrome-webrequest-to-the-current-tab-or-the-main-wi

Comment: Why aren't you using `chrome.tabs.onCreated` too? Also you can simplify the code: `return {cancel: details.url !== allowedURL};`